# Context for intent in onpostexecute is not null but getting null exception

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-asynctask, android-context

I've been stumped with this problem for two days now. I've checked this forum and other forums but can't get a question or answer close enough to my problem.

Basically I'm trying to execute an intent to `open an activity` from a non-activities `onpostexecute`, I'm sending the context (MainActivty.this) and string from a `onMarkerClick` function that is in a method in the MainActivity. This is going to a constructor in the non-activity which has the parameters for context and the string.

The issue is that I'm getting a null exception, but after debugging, the context is not null, it has the value of MainActivity, but when the intent is executed it returns a null exception. I've also tried many variations eg. Activity, getApplicationContext, this.context, (classname).context, (classname).this and tried a global context to no avail. The odd thing is I put the intent into an if statement if(context != null) and it passes through and it executes the intent which in turn gives me null exception which doesn't make sense. I know I'm new to android if anyone has any other suggestions on opening the activity that would be great thanks very much.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                       Process: com.example.quantusapps.joggertest, PID: 12253
>                                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                           at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:131)
>                                                                                           at android.content.ComponentName.(ComponentName.java:77)
>                                                                                           at android.content.Intent.(Intent.java:4029)
>                                                                                           at com.example.quantusapps.joggertest.BusCoachTramInfo.onPostExecute(BusCoachTramInfo.java:131)
>                                                                                           at com.example.quantusapps.joggertest.BusCoachTramInfo.onPostExecute(BusCoachTramInfo.java:25)
>                                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>                                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>                                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)<

**This is the Mainactivity Method with onMarkerClick**

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {


                String bctID = bctExtraMarkerInfo.get(marker.getId());
                BusCoachTramInfo busCoachTramInfo = new BusCoachTramInfo(bctID, MainActivity.this);
                busCoachTramInfo.execute(bctID);

                return false;
            }
        });
```

**This is the non-activity constructor.**

```
    Context context;

    BusCoachTramInfo(String busstopID, Context context) {

    this.context = context;

    naptanIdUrl = "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/StopPoint/" + busstopID + "/Arrivals?app_key=" + tfl_API_KEY + "&app_id=9c0b3009";



}
```

**This is where the null exception is happening.**

```
   @Override
protected void onPostExecute(TreeMap<Integer, String[]> Map) {
    super.onPostExecute(Map);

    Intent i = new Intent(context, BusArrivalTime.class);
    context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: The "non-activity" seems to be extending AsyncTask, is this correct?

Comment: Hi there yes it is , i did also try to put the extended asynctask in an inner class but i'm not sure if i did this well. thanks

Comment: I think it does not have to be an inner class of MainActivity, but IMO this is the easiest way. So if it's an inner class, you don't need the Context variable, just write "Mainactivity.this" and let's see what happens.(BTW no way to tell if you did it 100% right without seeing your code in one piece.)

Comment: I agree with you that this would be the easiest way without you not having seen the entire code,  but i will need to do this process about five times is this ok to have that many inner classes in the MainActivity.

Comment: Ummm... you're right, in this case I'd put the `AsyncTask` in some method of a standalone class. This method should take `MainActivity.this` as a parameter. As I have a feeling that you may be facing problems because an `Activity` is in fact more specialised than a `Context`, I'd suggest a parameter of type `MainActivity` (in fact better a `WeakReference` to your instance of `MainActivity`)

Comment: I have tried the WeakReference approach with no luck, but i will try it again as i didn't spend much time on it, also i have used the parameter MainActivity but still no luck. I don't know if this an odd question but do you think packaging my classes properly would help this situation. Thanks

Comment: First: it's ok to ask questions on SO. Now I don't know your project architecture. If you like you can post it (to Github?) and I'll look into it. But as long as everything compiles, I think you're safe. I just tested my code with a dummy Activity to jump to and only ` Thread.sleep(5000);` in `doInBackground()`, and it worked, sorry if it is not helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get things done is implementing the `AsyncTask` as part of a method which takes an instance of `MainActivity` as a parameter. The `AsyncTask` on the other hand would work with a `WeakReference`:

```
void doExecuteBusCoachTramInfo(final String busstopID, MainActivity activity){

    final WeakReference<MainActivity> wrActivity = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(MainActivity.this);
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, TreeMap<Integer, String[]>>(){

        @Override
        protected TreeMap<Integer, String[]> doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            // your code from BusCoachTramInfo here
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(TreeMap<Integer, String[]> integerTreeMap)
        {
            // get back to the original Activity if possible:
            MainActivity activity = wrActivity.get();
            if (activity != null){
                Intent i = new Intent(activity, BusArrivalTime.class);
                activity.startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

This method may be part of `MainActivity`, but it can just as well belong to some other class.

Comment: Very grateful for the code, i implemented the code in the non- activity class and in the MainActivity class. Unfortunately i got the same outcome of null exception for both classes. After debugging both classes i found out, that the context passes all the way through to the intent in both classes (using your code) but it still returns null exception at the end.

Comment: I believe that i might of done something to my project or may have over done it by adding to many things to it, causing some kind of confliction for it not to work even off the MainActivity. I have one other option to try which i'll try tonight and let you know as soon as possible. thanks again, also you have taught me a new way of doing AsyncTask through methods which will be very helpful in the future.

Comment: Hi, i still haven't found a reason for the null exception. But i found a work around to getting the activity to open using context for the Intent. I removed the entire method which contains my code and the onMarkerClick from MainActivity, and place it in the onPostExecute where the coordinates for my markers is retrieved. Then when the onMarkerclick is executed it passes my string variable and context parameters to a constructor in another class which extends AsyncTask. There my data is downloaded for the marker and in the onPostexecute the context for the Intent works and opens the Activity.

Comment: thank you very much for your code and help really appreciated. Hopefully someone will find a solution for this problem one day. Everyone take care.

Comment: @kash -  thanks for letting me know :) Why don't you write down how you solved the problem as an answer and accept it ( this is possible, at least after some time has passed)? It could be very helpful for others facing a similar problem.